# Is possible to create a transparent caramelization?

Tags: sugar

When you heat the sugar his color turns to yellow.

I'm doing something that heats the sugar(~110ºC), but I don't want it to become yellow.

Comment: It has to be possible, because Fox's Glacier Mints have done it for a century - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KdKM.jpg - but I've no idea how. [The slight yellow & blue cast in the photo is lighting; they are totally colourless in real life & probably a nightmare to photograph.]

Comment: I'd say look into sugar glass, this article goes pretty deep in the science of it: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/shattering-sugar-make-movie-ready-sugar-glass/

Answer (score 2):

It is possible and not particularly difficult to make candy that is completely clear.

However, it is not possible to have caramelization that is clear and colorless. When sugar is caramelized the sucrose begins to decompose from the heat. This gives us the distinctive delicious flavor but also changes the color of the sugar. It will go from yellow to brown to black... and then to the trash.

110C (230F) is not nearly hot enough to caramelize sugar-- that starts happening around 170C (340F). If you simply keep your syrup from overheating it will stay clear. As with all candy making, this is easier to do with an accurate thermometer and slow heat.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep an eye on your sugar and don't let it burn into caramel, and also find sugar with high purity.

The more uniform your heat the better, since if you don't have uniform some of your sugar will caramelize before the rest of it reaches "hard candy" doneness.